# When is $Inn(G)$ torsion-free?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely-generated, torsion-free group. Under what circumstances is $Inn(G)$, the group of inner automorphisms $\phi(x)=g^{-1}xg$ of $G$, torsion-free?

Since $Inn(G)\cong G/Z(G)$, the group $G$ modulo its centre, this is certainly true if $G$ is abelian, or, at the other extreme, centreless. But when else?

Apologies if this is too elementary, I am a topologist who does not know the group theory literature as well as he would like.

Comment: I am no group theorist either, but I think your question is way too general. BTW in the abelian case $Inn(G)$ is trivial, which I would not call torsion-free.

Comment: The trivial group is torsion free.

Comment: True for any torsion-free nilpotent group as well.

Comment: @Fernando: Fair enough. Perhaps I wanted to emphasize that torsion-free means "large" in some sense, while the trivial group is the "smallest" in any reasonable sense.

Comment: An example in which $G/Z(G)$ is not torsion-free is $\langle x,y \mid y^{-1}xy=x^{-1} \rangle$, because $y^2 \in Z(G)$.

Comment: @Steve D: This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. It would be great if you could give a proof or a reference as an answer. 

Comment: It is 1.2.20 in Lennox and Robinson's "The Theory of Infinite Soluble Groups".

Comment: @Steve D: Please post this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-relator ("large") example of a torsion free group such that the group of inner automorphisms has torsion:

$$\langle a_{1},a_{2},a_{3} : a_{1}^{2}=a_{2}^{3}, a_{2}^{5}=a_{3}^{7}\rangle$$.

This group is one-relator on $a_{1}$ and $a_{3}$, and by a result of Murasugi is torsion-free. The center of the group is generated by $a_{1}^{10}$.

This fact is mentioned in the first paragraph of this readily googlable paper of James McCool: *A class of one-relator groups with centre*, Bulletin of the Australian Mathematical Society, Volume 44, Issue 2, 2009.

The result is proved in this other readily googlable paper of Medskin, Pietrowski and Steinberg: *One relator groups with center*, Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society, Volume 16, 1973.

The result of Murasugi can be found in: *The center of a group with a single defining relation*, Math. Ann., 155, 1964.